# Add local hostname to azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I want to map a public IP address of a vm to a hostname. On a regular linux distribution I would add the ip to hostname mapping to `/etc/hosts` like so.

`52.123.12.23 name-to-resolve`

The question is how to achieve the same on a azure cloud shell(bash). So that if I want to ssh into a vm I don't need to remember or query the public IP.

> A pragmatic solution would be to create a simpel script to ssh into the vm.

Comment: you probably heard there is this thing called dns and there is this thing called reverse-search

Comment: Yes but i don't want to create a dns-record for this, I just want a simple local hostname mapping in the cloud shell instance. If it is not possible then I will create a CNAME to the public ip-address.

To clear things up I don't need reverse lookup simple hostname to ip is enough.

Comment: you can reverse search ip as well

Comment: Thanks you did help me a bit, I just assigned a dns to the public IP in azure which is easy, but still I would prefer a short local hostname that resolves to the public IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you cannot add the IP to hostname mapping to `/etc/hosts`, as the document says:

> Permissions are set as regular users without sudo access. Any
>   installation outside your $Home directory is not persisted.

And the /etc/hosts owner is root, you do not have the permission to edit it.
[image]

So, if you want to ssh the Azure VM without IP, you just can set a DNS to the VM Public IP.

There are some limitations to the Cloud Shell, you can get the details via this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/troubleshooting#general-limitations).